# STM32F4 Binary operation stucks in while(1)

Tags: c

```
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&I2cHandle, (uint16_t)I2C_ADDRESS, _DATAX0, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &data[0], 6, 10000); 

        temp = ((uint16_t)data[0]) << 8;

        BSP_LED_On(LED3);      
        HAL_Delay(50);
        BSP_LED_Off(LED3);      
        HAL_Delay(50);
    }
```

The data assignment to "temp" stucks the while cycle with no errors thrown. Do you have any idea what is causing this? Thank you.

Comment: you're saying this code freezes at the `temp = ((uint16_t)data[0]) << 8;` line?

Comment: I use "live variables" tool to plot data[], if I comment out the temp assignment, data[] updates correctly at each HAL_I2C_Mem_Read call. However, if the assignment made to temp is uncommented, data[] does no update anymore. Sorry, this might be a very silly problem, but I have just started with embedded. Thanks

Comment: strange. My first guess is undefined behavior elsewhere in your code that's not shown,, but I recently ran into a situation where `gdbserver` was reporting incorrect values for variables,, so don't implicitly trust your debugging tools. Try to verify `data` another way.

Comment: What does it mean "stuck"? HardFault? Something else?. It's not Linux - no errors are thrown.

Comment: Thanks yano! I will try something else

Comment: Please provide prototype of `data`. I have a hunch that it's memory mapped I/O.